# Cookies aren't persisting in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

#### How do I get the cookies to persist in php?

---

**give_cookie.php**

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["muffin"]))
        setcookie("muffin", "55", 100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    $_COOKIE["lid"]=true;
?>
```

**jar.php**

```
<?php
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    if($_COOKIE["lid"])
        echo "open";
?>
```

---

Running the code in that order gives me output:

> array(0) { } Notice: Undefined index: lid in jar.php on line 3

Embedding the code from `jar.php` in `give_cookie.php` gives me output:

> array(1) { ["lid"]=> bool(true) } open

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I need to add the expiry time to the current date?

Comment: Iirc, cookies are not available to PHP until the following request after setcookie. Someone correct me if wrong.

Comment: also, i'm not sure if setting $_COOKIE array will actually send the cookie. Try setcookie for "lid" too.

Comment: Note that the cookie is stored in the browser, not in PHP itself. If you send the cookie, the browser will send it back in the next request.

Comment: @JonStirling, you are right. However, he sets a value to the global variable `$_COOKIE["lid"]`, not set *properly*, so it will be available in the same script but not in the next refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to give a UNIX timestamp of when the cookie will expired (calculated since the epoch) as the third argument to the function call.

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
>   of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
>   this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
>   want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will
>   set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the
>   cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser
>   closes).

I suggest you read the documentation for [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Thanks, had omitted that `time()` function at some point from my code, not sure why. Will accept as answer in 10 mins.

Answer (score 1):

you're setting the cookie for `muffin` and trying to retrieve `lid` .you need to setcookie for `lid` as well.

Answer (score 1):

i think the time you are setting is still in the past

currently

```
time() = 1348584550

100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 =  259200000
```

so try

```
setcookie("muffin", "55", time() + (100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));

if($_COOKIE["muffin"])
    echo "open";
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are right, but there is another consideration. Cookies get set **when the server sends the html to the client**, and they are received from the user **when the user requests the page**. That means, if you try to read a cookie you just set *correctly*, it will be empty until next time the user reloads the page. The only way to avoid this is, as you did, not sure if on purpose or not, to assign manually the cookie's value and set it at the same time since it is a superglobal. This is NOT a good practice since the value of the Cookie gets lost for this execution. This should *work* but not do much work:

**give_cookie.php**

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["muffin"]))
        setcookie("muffin", "55", 100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    setcookie("lid", TRUE, time() + 100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    $_COOKIE["lid"]=TRUE;

?>
```

**jar.php**

```
<?php
    if($_COOKIE["lid"])
        echo "open";
?>
```

PS, there are many more problems with your code (besides it does nothing useful). Tell us what you are trying to achieve so we can help you a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, also is there an advantage to using `TRUE` over `true`?