# Setting cookies with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cookies aren't persisting in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585458/cookies-arent-persisting-in-php)

My objective is: when a user visits my website landing page and chooses their city (x or y), I would like to set a cookie that remembers this choice, so next time they visit the landing page it redirects straight to their city. The code I currently have is this:

landing page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['cambridge'])) {
    header('Location: http://cambridge.guestvibe.com');
}
else if (isset($_COOKIE['oxford'])) {
    header('Location: http://oxford.guestvibe.com');
}
?>
```

city-specific page (one example):

```
<?php setcookie("Cambridge",""); ?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<?php setcookie("Cambridge",""); ?>
```

This isn't working for me but it's my first time working with cookies. Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT**

The accepted answer solves half the problem, but for WordPress it's also necessary to add some code, explained [here](http://scratch99.com/wordpress/development/setting-cookies-in-wordpress-trap-for-beginners/).

Final code is:

```
setcookie('city','Cambridge',time()+86400*365, "/", ".guestvibe.com");
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable error_reporing? What does Firebug/Liveheaders etc. say?

Comment: No error flagged up by error reporting. Where am I looking in Firebug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because with your usage of `setcookie()` is bound to expire when the browser is closed. `setCookie` has a third parameter that you should use to set when it will expire. Leaving this out defaults to when the browser is closed. Here's an example on how to set a cookie that will expire in 365 days:

```
setcookie('city','Cambridge',time()+86400*365); // remember for 365 days.
```

Then, change your code to something like this:

```
if ($_COOKIE['city'] == 'Cambridge') {
    // redirect
} else if ($_COOKIE['city'] == 'Oxford') {
    // redirect
}
```

For more information about setting cookies, please check the PHP documentation for [setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it's not working for me. In case it helps, the homepage is www.guestvibe.com/index2.php and the city is cambridge.guestvibe.com.

Comment: were you able to note that after you use `setcookie()`, the data in `$_COOKIE` will not be accessible until the next request to the server (eg: page reload)?

Comment: I managed to fix this. It's also a WordPress issue. Extra bit added in original question.